# Searching Efficiency - Which is faster comparing 10 ints or one 30 bytes string?

Tags: database, string, performance, hash, numbers

I'm going to make a sentiment analysis project, with a website frontend to use it. It's designed to analise twitter posts. The analised documents will be put in a database.

I'm going to group retrieved posts by the search term in the database.

In order to make the database operations faster, I wouldn't like to compare search terms in strings, the idea is to transform the search terms into numbers and use them to find entries in the database.

The function I thought of to transform the strings in numbers would be something as follows:

- a = 067
- b = 068
- ...
- ab = 067068
- abc = 067068069
- abcd => i1= 067068069 and i2 = 070

This way, for a 30 length string, I would require 10 ints.

So 2 questions:
1- Would there be a better function to transform a 30 length string to a number, without ANY collision ?

2- In the case there isn't, in a database filed with a million search terms, would it be better to compare 10 ints per item, or compare 30 length string per item ?
 Something like

```
Select from terms where i1 == search.i1 and i2 = search.i2 and ... i10 == search.i10
```

OR

```
Select from terms where term like search.term
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: My best guess is:  If the entire string is arbitrary text, you're best off leaving it as a string.  Databases will already internally do any useful optimization like comparing the first 4 or 8 bytes with a single operation, esp. if it's a fixed-width string field.  OTOH, if there are only a few different possible values for search.i1, and a few other different possible values for search.i2, etc., then handling them separately might help the database indexing do a better job.